# Perimeter and Areas of similar triangles

Tags: geometry

Just want to make sure I've done this right because it has been years since I've done geometry.

1. $\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle DEF$. The ratio of the sides from $\triangle ABC$ to $\triangle DEF$ is $3:5$. If the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ is $24$ what is the perimeter of $\triangle DEF$?

To solve this, I did $$\frac{3}{5}=\frac{24}{x} \implies x=40.$$

2. $\triangle$ JKL is similar to $\triangle QRT$. The ratio of the sides from $\triangle JKL$ to $\triangle QRT$ is $5:2$. If the area of $\triangle JKL$ is 100, what is the area of $\triangle QRT$?

For this one I first used a triangle with sides $1, 1, \sqrt2$. The area of this triangle is  $\frac{1}{2}$. Then I used the given proportion to find a triangle that is similar. This triangle has sides $\frac{5}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{5\sqrt2}{2}$ and the area is $3\frac{1}{8}$. The area from the first triangle to the second one changed by a factor of $\frac{3\frac{1}{8}}{1/2}=6\frac{1}{4}$. Thus, the area of $\triangle QRT$ is $(100)(6\frac{1}{4})=625$.

Comment: $\dfrac{100}{6\frac14} = 16$. The sides of $\triangle QRT$ are smaller, so intuitively, the area should be smaller as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly , in (1) You are correct.

Again for checking:

Let the sides of 1st one are, $3a,3b,3c$ and the 2nd one are $5a,5b,5c.$

Hence perimeter of 1st one is $3(a+b+c)$ and 2nd one is $5(a+b+c)$.Thus,ratio of perimeters of the triangles is also $3:5$.

$\therefore$ You are correct definitely!

Next,in Second problem,you have done a small mistake.
You have taken the sides of 1st traingle as $1, 1, \sqrt2$ ,and you have got 2nd triangle has sides $\frac{5}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{5\sqrt2}{2}$ , which is wrong.

Because Here the ratio of sides =$\frac{1}{\frac{5}{2}}$=$\frac 25$=$2:5$

(But given,the ratio is $5:2$).

So, correcting your calculations,

Area of 1st triangle is  $\frac{1}{2}$.
2nd triangle has sides $\frac25, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{2\sqrt2}{5}$ and the area is $\frac 12.\frac 4{25}=\frac 2{25}$. The area from the first triangle to the second one changed by a factor of $\frac{\frac{2}{25}}{\frac 12}=\frac{4}{25}$. Thus, the area of $\triangle QRT$ is $(100)(\frac{4}{25})=16$.

Answer (score 1):

When 1-dimensional perimeters are in a ratio (scale factor) s, the areas of the shapes are in a ratio of $s^2$ (since area is 2-dimensional). So the ratio of the areas of △JKL:△QRT is $(5/2)^2 = 25/4$.  This means the area of △JKL is 25/4 that of △QRT, which means the latter's area is 16 square units.